# The img src property is sending my requests to a different route

Tags: node.js, html, path, ejs, multer

I'm storing images on my MongoDB using Express and Multer, so far everything works fine, the image is stored in the uploads folder and I get the req.file.path attribute.

The problem is when I try to set that path to an img tag trough EJS, I set the src to be the path that Multer provided but it sends me somewhere else.

I set the uploads folder to be static using 
`app.use(express.static("uploads"));`

and when I render my EJS template I set the img source as follows: 
`<img src="<% paciente.datosGrafo3 %>" alt="GRAFO 3">`

`paciente.datosGrafo3 is equal to "uploads\descarga.png"`

But when I open the app in the browser this is the link that shows in my src:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYLi3.png)

Pacientes is another model and route I have in my app but I don't know why it is acting as a prefix to my src.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `upload` is your only static folder? From which folder do you serve other static files (css, js) ?

Comment: @dimitristseggenes I have another static folder called `public` where I serve my css and js.

Comment: In case `upload` is your static folder from which you serve your images, then your image src shouldn't include `/upload` path. For example  `paciente.datosGrafo3` hasto be equal to `"/descarga.png"`

Comment: @dimitristseggenes `paciente.datosGrafo3` is the file.path provided by multer, I can't set it manually. It still doesn't explain why there's `pacientes/` at the beginning of the route tough.